# How to get the default value of key from the registry

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I am trying get the `(Default)` key value from the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and the code snippet I tried is as below,

```
using (var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"Excel.Application\\CurVer"))
{
    var defvalue = key?.GetValue("(Default)");
    if (defvalue != null)
    {
    }
}
```

Always the `defvalue` is coming as null. I am not able trace out what mistake I am doing.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Pass `null` instead of "(Default)"

Comment: @AleksAndreev, Thank you that did the trick.

Answer (score 31):

Instead of using `"(Default)"`, you'll need to use an empty string (`""`).

```
using (var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"Excel.Application\\CurVer"))
{
    var defvalue = key?.GetValue("");
    if (defvalue != null)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with "String.Empty" to get "(Default)" value of registry instead of accessing "(Default)" in your code.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead